# How to wait for all ajax queries to finish (and use combined result)

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

```
var display_message="";
            $('input:checked').each(function(index) {

               var profile_id=$(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                            type: 'post',
                            url: 'myUrl',
                            data: data,
                            success: function(data) {
                                if(data=="ok")
                                    display_message = display_message + data +", ";
                            }
                    });
           });

           alert(display_message);
           alert(display_message);

           if($.trim(display_message)!=""){
                jAlert("Your birthdate already exits in "+display_message.substring(0, display_message.length - 2)+".", "Bdate");
                 return false;
           }
```

in this code, i use two alert-box for display display_message variable value.
when i run successfully this code, in 1st alert-box i get blank value and second alert-box i get value which i needed, then it will go in if condition.
if i doesn't use alert box then it will always take null value in display_message variable and never enters into the if condition. so what i need to change to run this code without alert box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making an asynchronous call via AJAX, but your code is executing synchronously. So it is returning before the AJAX call completes. The first alert box just gives the function time to catch up. You need to handle all this code in your success callback.

```
    var display_message="";
    $('input:checked').each(function(index) {

       var profile_id=$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'myUrl',
                    data: data,
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data=="ok")
                            display_message = display_message + data +", ";
                        if($.trim(display_message)!=""){
                           jAlert("Your birthdate already exits in "+display_message.substring(0, display_message.length - 2)+".", "Bdate");
         return false;
                    }
            });
   });
```

Comment: dear mrtsherman, i cant use if condition in each loop.i use if condition outside loop, because i add the data in disaplay_message varible and if it doesn't null then it will go in if condition and return false;

Answer (score 1):

You want all your ajax queries to finish and return results, right?

Then this is a synchronization problem.

I would suggest this approach (code is simplified for clarity).

```
var inputs_processed = -1;
var inputs_to_process = -1;

function queryData() {
  inputs_to_process = $('input:checked').length;

  $('input:checked').each(function() {
    $.ajax({success: function(data) {
      inputs_processed += 1;
      // build up that message
    }});
  });
}

function displayResult() {
  if (inputs_processed == inputs_to_process) {
    // display result
  } else {
    // not all queries finished yet. Wait.
    setTimeout(displayResult, 500);
  }
}

queryData();
displayResult();
```

Basically, you know how many requests should be made and you don't display result until that number of requests returns.

Comment: Ahhh, his question finally makes sense to me. Nice job.

Answer (score 0):

Why your data is "data"? I cant see any variable called data is declared here. You should pass in the value you want to use as the parameter into the data options.

Edit: This is why u getting the null value. data is not initialize into anything. Only after the success function, your "data" will have the value since you declare the return value with the same name

Comment: the you can just add async: false in your ajax. An alternative as what suggested by mrtsherman

Comment: i cant use if condition in each loop.i use if condition outside loop, because i add the data in disaplay_message varible and if it doesn't null then it will go in if condition and return false;

Comment: my solution do not need the if condition, just add one async:false after your url: 'myUrl'